# Highlight search text in TextArea with Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am trying to highlight a search text in TextArea with scrollTop.
I found the below logic, Its working to highlight text with range but calculation of scrollTop height is not reaching to the matched text position.

```js
//findIndex--Position of matched word in TextArea
//res -- search result.
//data --- TextArea data
//dataLength  -- Total length of TextArea content.

var taElement = document.getElementById("textareasource");
 taElement.focus();
 taElement.setSelectionRange(findIndex, res.length + findIndex);
 var sh = taElement.scrollHeight;
 var patt = new RegExp("</p>", "g");
 var newLineCount = data.match(patt).length;
 var line_ht = 15; //line hight of content.
 var n_lines = sh / line_ht-newLineCount;
 var char_in_line = dataLength / n_lines;
 var height = Math.abs(Math.floor(findIndex / char_in_line));
 taElement.scrollTop = height * line_ht;
```

I tried TextArea with wrap off also not working. Any one please suggest me how shall i resolve this. Appreciate your response.

Comment: *not working as expected*... and exactly how are we supposed to know what you think should be *expected*??

Comment: @freefaller: Thanks for reply. Mean to say..Its not scrolling to the matched word position.